# Qt3D Different Material for different RenderPasses

Tags: qt, qml, rendering, qt3d

I have a QML Scene3D with 2 viewports, left and right half of window. The scene contains two cameras (one per viewport) and a torus mesh. I want to use a viewport-specific material for the same torus, i.e. different QMaterials (QEffects, QShaderPrograms, ...) when rendering in the left and right viewport respectively.

```js
// main.qml

Entity {
    id: rootEntity

    components: [
        MyFrameGraph {
            camLeft: cameraLeft
            camRight: cameraRight
        },
        InputSettings { }
    ]

    Camera {
        id: cameraLeft
        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
        position: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, -200.0 )
        upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
        viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
    }

    Camera {
        id: cameraRight
        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
        position: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 200.0, 0.0 )
        upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
        viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
    }

    TorusMesh {
        id: torusMesh
        radius: 20
        minorRadius: 5
    }

    Transform {
        id:torusTransform
    }

    Material{
        id: myTorusMaterial
        effect: MyEffect{}
    }

    Entity {
        id: torus
        components: [torusMesh,torusTransform,myTorusMaterial]
    }
}
```

My FrameGraph contains two branches for the two viewports, whereas the leaf nodes are RenderPassFilters.

```js
//MyFrameGraph.qml

RenderSettings {
    id: root

    property Camera camLeft
    property Camera camRight

    activeFrameGraph: RenderSurfaceSelector {
        id: surfaceSelector

        Viewport {
            id: mainViewport
            normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)

            ClearBuffers {
                buffers: ClearBuffers.ColorDepthBuffer
                clearColor: "black"
            }

            Viewport {
                normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1)
                CameraSelector {
                    camera: root.camLeft
                    RenderStateSet {
                        renderStates: [
                            DepthTest {depthFunction: DepthTest.Less}
                        ]
                        RenderPassFilter {
                            matchAny: [FilterKey { name: "pass"; value: "myMaterialLeft" }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Viewport {
                normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1)
                CameraSelector {
                    camera: root.camRight
                    RenderStateSet {
                        renderStates: [
                            DepthTest {depthFunction: DepthTest.Less}
                        ]

                        RenderPassFilter {
                            matchAny: [FilterKey { name: "pass"; value: "myMaterialRight" }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my custom Material/Effects I use FilterKeys in the RenderPass object.

```js
//MyEffect.qml

Effect {
    id: root

    property color maincolor: Qt.rgba(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)

    ShaderProgram {
        id: myShaderLeft
        vertexShaderCode: loadSource("qrc:/shader/myShaderLeft.vert")
        fragmentShaderCode: loadSource("qrc:/shader/myShaderLeft.frag")
    }
    ShaderProgram {
        id: myShaderRight
        vertexShaderCode: loadSource("qrc:/shader/myShaderRight.vert")
        fragmentShaderCode: loadSource("qrc:/shader/myShaderRight.frag")
    }

    parameters: [
        Parameter {
             name: "maincolor"
             value: Qt.vector3d(root.maincolor.r, root.maincolor.g, root.maincolor.b)
         }
    ]

    techniques: [
        Technique {
            filterKeys: [FilterKey { name: "renderingStyle"; value: "forward" }]

            graphicsApiFilter {
                api: GraphicsApiFilter.OpenGL
                profile: GraphicsApiFilter.CoreProfile
                majorVersion: 3
                minorVersion: 1
            }
            RenderPass {
                id:renderPassLeft
                filterKeys: [ FilterKey { name: "pass"; value: "myMaterialLeft" } ]

                shaderProgram: myShaderLeft
                renderStates: [CullFace { mode: CullFace.NoCulling }]
            }
            RenderPass {
                id: renderPassRight
                filterKeys: [ FilterKey { name: "pass"; value: "myMaterialRight" } ]

                shaderProgram: myShaderRight
                renderStates: [CullFace { mode: CullFace.NoCulling }]
            }
            renderPasses:[renderPassLeft,renderPassRight]
        }
    ]
}
```

This works as expected, the object is rendered with `myShaderLeft` in the left viewport and with `myShaderRight` in the right viewport.

Now I want to use an default Qt-material (QMetalRoughMaterial) when rendering in the left viewport, and my custom material/effect when rendering in the right viewport. How can I achieve that?

An idea was to access the ShaderProgram of the MetalRoughMaterial through `metalRougMaterial.effect.techniques[0].renderPasses[0].shaderProgram` and use it one of the RenderPasses of my custom Material/Effect. However, `metalRougMaterial.effect.techniques` returns an undefined object.

```js
MetalRoughMaterial {
    id: metalRoughMaterial
    baseColor: "red"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [source code](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/dev/src/extras/defaults/qmetalroughmaterial.h), it looks like `effect` is not a property that you can access on the material.

I'm not sure if this will work but I guess you could subclass the material in C++ and make the effect accessible. This way, you could modify it in QML, once you've registered it as a new QML type and used this QML type instead of the normal material one.

Another option that I can think of would be to create the object twice, once of the right viewport and once for the left. Then create two `QLayer`s and add one to each and two respective `QLayerFilter`s for each framegraph branch, to which you also add one layer each.

I gues computationally this comes down to the same load but you'd have to think about how setting position etc. works (I think you can add the same `QTransform` to both, but I'm not sure).

Last but not least you could probably recreate the whole material in QML completely (with your filter key) but that's probably a lot of work.